Can we use 'our' to replace 'us' in "Us being strike ready means we're fed up, …."
From Teamsters union launching strike against Amazon in NYC, across country

Us being strike ready means we're fed up, and Amazon is clearly
ignoring us, and we want to be heard.

Can we use 'Our' or 'We' here? What is the reason that 'Us' is used here, for emphasis?

Our being ready would be the most formally 'correct' version - see this from ELU.
Us being ready is natural and acceptable. It implies 'the fact of us being ready'.
We being ready would sound odd.

Btw, the reasoning behind a preference for the genitive (here, the our) is illustrated by consideration of questions like “What is the head (‘main noun,’ if you will) of the object of the verb hate in I hate Jane being inconvenienced? Clearly, the thing that is hated is not Jane—indeed, the speaker may be madly in love with Jane—but some inconveniencing. Which inconveniencing? The inconveniencing of Jane, which is to say, “Jane’s being inconvenienced.” (So the head is the gerund being.)

An additional way to see it is to consider that Jane’s dying is essentially parallel to Jane’s death.  We would never say, for instance, *”I was saddened by Jane death.”

Agree, although I don't think unpacking it as "the fact of us being ready" clarifies much, as to my ear the "correct" rendering here is also "the fact of our being ready" (or better, "the fact that we are ready").
